# what does the "ctx" really doing discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

Im programming a discord bot in Python
and every tutorial on Youtube telling me that i have to use the 'ctx' when im making a command,
but none of those Youtubers explaining what this is doing, so pls can someone answer me?

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html):

> A command must always have at least one parameter, `ctx`, which is the `Context` as the first one.

Now, what is `Context`? Again, [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context):

> Represents the context in which a command is being invoked under.

> This class contains a lot of meta data to help you understand more about the invocation context. This class is not created manually and is instead passed around to commands as the first parameter.